# Google Big Query doesn't show only project specific datasets

Tags: google-bigquery

I have three projects on GCP which play the role of three environments (dev, staging, prod. Each of them has a corresponding dataset on Big Query created as follows:

```
bq --location=${REGION} mk \
--dataset \
${DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID}:mydataset

bq mk \
--table \
${DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID}:mydataset.mytable \
schema.json
```

When executing that in the dev shel on GCP, I have my **Dev** project selected.

[image]

And, when I execute

> bq ls

in the shell I can see only this dataset available there which is expected.

After that, after switching to another project and executing

> bq ls

Again, only one data set is visible and it is the one dedicated to the staging environment, for example. But when I open the UI of Google Big Query (using the staging project), I can see my **Dev** environment/project dataset.

[image]

I am wondering why is that and is it normal and expected?

Answer (score 1):

It is totally normal behavior. The Resources section contains a list of pinned projects. Expand a project to view datasets and tables that you have access to. You can manually pin/unpin your datasets in each project. A search box is available in the Resources section that allows you to search for resources by name or by label.

Please, refer to [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui). I hope it helps.

Comment: What I don't understand here is why do I see only my DEV dataset if DEV project is selected on GCP and I can see DEV + STAGING when Staging project is selected and DEV + PROD when Production project is selected. I didn't do anything special when creating those datasets. All of the three were created in the exactly same way.

Comment: It is inexplicable behavior, at least you can manually change it after creating new project.